# Excel VBA Textfile to 2d array

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel vba. I want to read a textfile that contains text like this:

```
John Smith Engineer Chicago 
Bob Alice Doctor New York 
Jane Smith Teacher St. Louis
```

So, I want to convert this into a 2D array so if I do print(3,3), it should return 'Teacher'. 
I am able to read entire file contents into one string but am having difficulty in converting it to
a 2d array like above. Please advice on how to proceed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

unless the text file has some specific structure to it, you're going to struggle a bit. Things that might make it easier are:

- Does the text file contain line breaks at the end of each line?
- Are all the names in [FirstName][LastName] format as per your example
  or might some have more/less words?
- Does the Occupation always come directly after the name?
- Are there a (very) limited number of Occupations?

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by NautMeg, You have to make some assumptions on the data based on the provided template.

However we can assume that :

- a space is the delimiter
- The Final column is City, which can contain a space
- there are 4 columns

  - First Name
  - Last Name
  - Profession
  - City/Location

Using this information:

```
While Not EOF(my_file)
    Line Input #my_file, text_line
    // text_line contains the independent line
    i = i + 1
    // i is the line number
Wend
```

is how we retrieve each line.

```
Split ( Expression, [Delimiter], [Limit], [Compare] )
```

This will give you each item in the list. For index's < 3 (0 based index), they are unique columns of data and you can handle them however you want.
For Index >=3, Join these together into 1 string .

```
Join( SourceArray, [Delimiter] )
```

You'll likely want to make the delimiter in this case a simple space, since the split function will remove the space.

That will allow you to parse the data AS is.

However, for future reference if you can control the export of the text file, you should try exporting as a CSV file.

Good luck